# Pattern design for a WebService Client

Tags: android, web-services, design-patterns

I'm making an android application that will contact with a WebServices that exists already.

I'm looking for a pattern to create the client part (Android application). Since the webservices are in .net (WSDL), I have to create the WSClient manually. So, I'm thinking How I can do it.

I thought that may be nice a WS Client class and for that, a singleton pattern. With that class, I could contact with all the services from any part for the application, but I don't know if this is the best choise.

Any suggerence please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service locator, dependency Injection and
inversion of Control, patterns.
A good paper is to [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://goo.gl/H9a5z) by M. Fowler.

Comment: :Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)